# React- Use hook within a map?

Tags: reactjs

I was hoping I could sneak past the rule of hooks on this one, but alas, no. I have a custom hook that takes in a user's Id, sends a call to the backend, and returns the full name of the user. On another component, I have a useEffect that maps out an array of actions done on a given user (suspending/reinstating access) that details the date and the user who did the action.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(suspendHistory?.length) {
          const withNames =  suspendHistory.map((i, idx) => {
                let suspender = useGetUserName(i.susBy)
                let reinstater = useGetUserName(i.reinBy)
                return(
                    <>
                        <ol key={idx}>
                            <li>Suspended on: {new Date(i.susOn).toLocaleDateString()}</li>
                            <li>Suspended By: {suspender} </li>
                            {i.reinBy? (
                                <>
                                    <li>Reinstated on: {new Date(i.reinOn).toLocaleDateString()}</li>
                                    <li>Reinstated by: {reinstater}</li>
                                </>
                            ): (
                                <></>
                            )} <br />
                        </ol>
                    </>
                )
            })
            setNamedHistory(withNames)
        }
    }, [suspendHistory])
```

Since I want to call the custom hook on whatever Ids are being returned in the map, is there any way for me to get that custom hook call made without breaking the rule of hooks? Or do I just need to rethink how I'm storing the info on the backend? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a custom hook that takes in a user's Id, sends a call to the backend, and returns the full name of the user.

Therein lies the problem.  *The hook* shouldn't do this.  It should *provide a function* which does this.

So instead of a hook like this:

```
const useGetUserName = (x) => {
  // function logic
}
```

You would have this:

```
const useUserInfo = () => {
  const getUserName = (x) => {
    // function logic
  }

  return { getUserName };
}
```

Then at the start of your component you can get the function from the hook:

```
const { getUserName } = useUserInfo();
```

And then you can call that function wherever you like in the component.

Comment: In addition, `useEffect` must not return `jsx`. Keep the return for any `componentDidUnmount` actions. More infos in the `react` documentation

Comment: @devpolo: It isn't returning JSX.  It's (conditionally) building up some JSX and setting it to state.  (Which is also... unusual.  But not technically wrong in and of itself I don't think, though I could be mistaken on that point.)  The effect itself isn't returning anything here.

Comment: (Though, as an aside... Given the use of putting JSX into state and the indication that `getUserName` performs an asynchronous operation, I **strongly suspect** that there are other problems in this application not being addressed here.)

Comment: True. I didn’t paid enough attention! Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I take your points on the useEffect and putting JSX into state, this was my first try at doing that to navigate the conditional before performing the map, it worked for that and I didnt think it farther. Also, @David, I hear you on the function inside the hook component, however using RTK Query, the api calls are done with hooks as well, which had me going without the inner function. I'll see what I can do to make that work as you suggest, thanks